# Electron unable to load preload.js problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

It took 3 days to set up electron & react myself. By the time I thought it was all there was a new problem

[image]

I want to connect electron with react. but i can't get preload.js file

If there is no preload.js file, both execution and build work fine. but After adding the preload.js file, it says that the preload.js file cannot be found (otherwise it works fine)

I tried a lot of attempts, such as changing the settings of electron's webPreferences that came out after searching, but all failed.

I don't know how to solve this problem. Thanks for telling me how to fix it.
I have attached several parts of my code

The picture below is my folder structure

[image]

this is my electron code

```js
// electron/main.js
import { app, BrowserWindow } from "electron";
import path from "path";

let mainWindow;
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload: path.resolve(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
  });

  if (isDev) {
    mainWindow.loadURL(`http://localhost:3000`);
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  } else {
    mainWindow.loadFile(`${path.join(__dirname, "/index.html")}`);
  }

  mainWindow.on("closed", () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);
app.allowRendererProcessReuse = true;
```

and this is my preload.js

```js
// electron/preload.js

import { ipcRenderer } from "electron";

process.once("loaded", () => {
  window.ipcRenderer = ipcRenderer;
});
```

and this is my package.json
[image]

Finally this is my webpack.electron.config.js

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  entry: "./electron/main.js",
  target: "electron-main",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
};
```

Comment: There are [a number of templates](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/wiki/State-of-Electron-frameworks-%5BMay-2021%5D) you can start with that have the necessary setup to get you off the ground running.